# How can I draw a straight line using ZingChart?

Tags: javascript, visualization, zingchart

The end result should look something like this. See the LSL line? How could I draw that, is there a way to force a draw on the first value? Or should I just draw an overlay?

[image: The end result]

The attempt(inside series)

```
valueBox:{
    visible:true,
    color:"red",
    text:"LPL"
},
type:'line',
"line-style":"dashed",
lineWidth: 1,
"values":[max+1],
lineColor:"red",
"marker":{ visible:false}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a minor-guide, and then set the index check to where you want it.

```
"minor-guide":{
                    rules:[{
                    rule:'%scale-index === 0',
                    alpha:1,
                    lineStyle: 'dashed',
                    lineWidth:1,
                    lineColor:"red",
                    visible:true
                }]
```